# Checkbox still gets unchecked despite using preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

When `getInfo()` returns `false`, the window `alert` is thrown however the checkbox still gets changed; checked if unchecked and vice versa.

Any help?

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event) {
  var someCondition = getInfo();
  if (someCondition === false) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.alert("Nope");
    return false;
  }
});

function getInfo() {
  return false; // just for testing
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it: your code is working as expected. Also, avoid using `alert()` since it blocks script execution. Use `console.log()` and check your devtools console. Try console logging `someCondition`: are you sure it is evaluating to `false`?

Comment: I have placed your code in a snippet where it works absolutely fine. Check to ensure there's no errors in the console and that you're running your jQuery code after the DOM has loaded. Also ensure that `getInfo()` is returning `false`, not `'false'` or `0`.

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced. Maybe you need to clear your cookies and cache and then try again.

Comment: Your code is working as you explained in the description.

Comment: Is `getInfo()` using an asynchronous call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you need correctly you could just use this

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function (event) {
         var someCondition = getInfo();
         if(someCondition === false) {
            var checkVal = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
             $("input[type='checkbox']").attr( "checked", !checkVal );
             window.alert("Nope");

         }
     });
```

Or if you want checkbox to be un-checked if your condition is false

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function (event) {
         var someCondition = getInfo();
         if(someCondition === false) {
             $("input[type='checkbox']").attr( "checked", false);
             window.alert("Nope");

         }
     });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Why would the OP need to make this more complicated than his existing working code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work on fiddle, but some other plugin might be interfering with the behavior. Still, try the following and see if this solves the issue

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click',function (event) {
        var someCondition = getInfo();
        var checkBox = $(this);
        if(someCondition === false) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            checkBox.prop('checked', !checkBox.prop('checked'))
            window.alert("Nope");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why would the OP need to make this more complicated than his existing working code?